# Running on real device shows different UI then in layout editor

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-editor

I have built an alert cardview that pops up to prompt a response from the user.  I am using constraint layout, and the view looks correct in the layout editor.  I have even tested in on multiple screen sizes in the editor and the constraints work properly.  But when I go running it on a real device the view doesn't follow the constraints.

Here is how it looks in the layout editor:

[image: Layout Editor Image]

This is how it shows up on a real device:

[image: Real Device Image]

Here is the XML script for the card view:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/phoneCardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#333333"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Your charger is just 3 clicks away!"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#67bca2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textfieldbackground"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="PHONE NUMBER"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#4d000000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/errorMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/promoCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textfieldbackground"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="PROMO CODE"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#4d000000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneNumber" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="#4dffffff"
            android:onClick="registerClick"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#67bca2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="#4dffffff"
            android:onClick="cancelClick"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#67bca2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#333333"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am using the following relevant dependencies:

```
'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: why you limit to  android:layout_height="300dp", thats awfully alot of pixels which can vary per screen size

Comment: I have tested it on a 3.7" screen and am not considered with it being an issue as far as fitting on a screen.  Unless you think it is causing the issue with the layout. I had a feeling it had to do with constraint layout but I don't see any conflicting constraints.  In xcode for iOS I havent had any issues like this.

Comment: beleive me, IOS layouts are something else. But yea, did you utilized the drag and drop ?

Comment: drag and drop? Like drop the widgets in and use constraints by pulling the edges of the widgets to the edges of another?

Comment: Yes the visual drag and drop is reccomended for contraint layout, even google said it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XamMbnzI5vE

Comment: yes I did do that, have you tried to build it yourself?

Comment: using the above method, yes, by nature its a trial and error

Comment: are you getting the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your problems (the buttons at the bottom not being clipped by the card and the divider between buttons appearing too large) are caused by platform-version-specific behavior that is built into `CardView`. From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html):

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms before Lollipop, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection

I've run your code on an API 16 emulator, and I see the same problems you're having.

You can try adding this attribute to your top-level `<CardView>` tag:

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

though this is not necessarily a magic fix-all.

As for fixing the divider between buttons, is there a reason you're using a `<CardView>` tag for the divider? I just changed it to a `<View>` tag and it seems to work well:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#333333"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4"/>
```

Comment: Ahh yes I am running it on a device using API 19 and lollipop is 21.  I guess i'll just set the cardview to clip if the API is 21 or higher.  Unless you have a better idea on how to give the illusion of clipping?  I also changed from cardview to view for the divider.  Thanks